# Speed up the algebraic computation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 1000 text files including 6 columns and I have to compute a simple algebraic operation using come columns in each file and then plotting a simple plot of the result but it took more than 6 hours of computation. It is a bit strange just for this little thing, taking that much of time. here is the code:

```
modes = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('config')]

maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in RIVERS])
modes = ['configuration_%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]

for i, d in enumerate(modes):

    a = np.loadtxt(d).T 
    x = a[0]
    y = a[1]
    for l in range(len(x)):
        l_c = np.sqrt((y[-1]-y[0])**2 + (x[-1]-x[0])**2)

    j = a[2]
    for k in range(len(j)):
        l_i = j[-1]-j[0]
        sigma = l_i/l_c
        plt.plot(sigma)
    #tt = np.arange(0,1000)
    #plt.plot(tt,sigma)

plt.show()
```

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the values of maxnum? How about range(len(x)) and range(len(j))

Comment: @jmh not yet, but what should be checked? I mean after checking what measures should be taken into account?

Comment: Are you sure this works for just one file?   That `l_c` iteration looks wrong.  And a separate `plot` for each `k` is probably wrong, or at least slow.  I think you should provide a working example using a reduced size file, or a copy-n-paste of the `a` variable.

Comment: you determine the variable magnum in the code. Does it get set properly? same with the other 2. A one-line print command should give those values. its an easy check to be sure code is running properly.

Comment: I'm not sure that the calculation (even if done wrong) is the slow step.  `loadtxt` for a 1000 files takes time, so does all those plots.

Comment: @hpaulj I checked, for each file, it works fine but when I want to impose loops, it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You could use Multithreading or Multiprocessing to speed this up.
Easiest way would be using the *Threading* module.

[Python Documentation: Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

A simplefied example:

```
import threading

#Define how many threads you want
numberOfThreads = 5

#Create threads
threads = [threading.Thread(target=myFunction, args=(myArguments,)) for _ in range(0, numberOfThreads)]

    #Start all threads
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    #Script waits until last thread has finished
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

def myFunction(myArguments):
    #Do calculation
```

If you have 1k txt files to process i recommend the *Queue* module. The Queue contains the path to all files and your threads pick one by another to process.

[Python Documentation: Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

A simplefied example:

```
from queue import Queue

#Create Queue object
q = Queue()

#Put item to queue
q.put("/myPath/filename.txt")

#Get and process each item in queue and remove it (so it gets processed only once)
while not q.empty():
    myPath = q.get()
```

The threads are still running on one processor core. If the speedgain is still unsatisfied you should use multiprocessing instead of multithreading.

I recommend the *concurrent.futures* module. This works almost similar to the threading examples.

[Python Documentation: concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve math and any algebraic operation, first of all, taken into account, to prepare a void space to save variable values into. This thing makes a significant contribution to an increase in efficiency of the code e.g. using `my_list=[]` and then using `my_list.append(var)` . Another way is by using prepared libraries rather than writing from scratch.